# Driver not load QT

Tags: qt, qt5, qtcreator, qt-designer

Драйвер не найден, как исправить?
QT, UNIX система
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если мне память не изменяет, драйвер для Firebird в поставку не входит, его надо собирать из исходников, либо искать пакет. Какой у вас дистрибутив?

Comment: Red Os(на базе Linux)

Comment: У вас два варианта, даже три.
1) Обращаетесь в поддержку этого чуда. 
2) Ищете пакет.
3) Собираете недостающее из исходников.

Comment: а на примере Linux как сделать?

Comment: Кстати, у вас опечатки нет? Что за IDASE?

Comment: штатно драйвер для interbase/firebird с QT не поставляется из-за особенностей лицензирования. драйвер необходимо собирать ручками. см. https://evileg.com/en/post/157/